# Similar to Extension Methods Functionality - Can we extend properties

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

Extension methods are a great way to extend the functionality of a type.
Are there any ways similar to this which can be used to extend properties of a class without inheriting a new class.

Comment: Do you mean adding new properties to an object by using something similar like extension methods?

Comment: you can *kind of* add new properties to a class from a different file, if the class is declared as `partial`.  Without declaring a class as `partial`, there are no "extension properties".

Comment: Are you working with WPF? You can do [Attached Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms749011(v=vs.100).aspx) which basically work like "extension properties" but they are WPF only.

Comment: Thanks @dotnetom. trying to find out if it is possible to add properties to a class without inheriting it.

Comment: Thanks @Claies but partial class cannot be used from an external dll / library

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain . But I am using Web API to expose the objects.

Answer (score 3):

No extension properties **do not exist**.

You can't do it via properties without inheriting a new class. There are only extension methods, not extension properties (*it may be added at a future date*). If you don't want to alter the original class you should inherit from the original class and then add your properties to the derived class.